# Installer built with PackageMaker only sometimes shows destination select screen

Tags: osx-lion, packagemaker

I have built a simple installer with PackageMaker 3.0.5.  It installs a package into /Applications and some support files into /Library.

The distribution is set to easy install only, System volume only.  Allow custom location is disabled for all of the contents.  The app is set to allow downgrade and not allow relocation.

The installer does install correctly, but sometimes when I run the installer it displays a 'Select a Destination' screen and has a 'Change Install Location...' button, and sometimes it skips straight through to the 'Installation Type' screen.

I would prefer the second behaviour, but could live with either.  My concern is the unexplained change in behaviour betweens runs.  Does anyone know what causes this, and how to stop it?

Comment: ... having the opposite problem -- I want to let User choose where part of it goes, the rest goes only to certain location.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've been able to determine, it has to do with the version of OS X where the installer is being run.

I built my installer using PackageMaker 3.0.3 on Mac OS X 10.5 and I have all the same settings you do.

When installing on OS X 10.5 I do not get the Destination Select pane, or the "Change Install Location..." button. But on 10.6 and 10.7 I see both.

I also have a custom install pane, which may changes things.

Sorry this isn't a real answer but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm running the installer on 10.7 and sometimes get the destination and location screens, and sometimes don't.  I haven't been able to determine any pattern as to when I get them.

Comment: @LukeGraham: I'm seeing the same 'sometimes' behavior as you described.  I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.  Have you figured out what's causing that?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on OS X Yosemite. Sometimes "destination select" shows up and sometimes not. Usually on the first time it shows up, but on consecutive runs it does not.